# Amazon sns push notifications

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I have already installed this package https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel to send AMAZON SNS push notifications to mobile devices, but I am having troubles to configure it.
I dont know where to find `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and
`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

```
return [
   'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
    ],
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',

    // You can override settings for specific services
    'Ses' => [
        'region' => 'us-east-1',
    ],
];
```

Comment: You need to generate them, (or get them) from your AWS console assuming this is running on a dev env not on AWS.